# Range is not working when submit form (django)

Tags: javascript, python, django, for-loop, range

we were working with Django and we have got a problem. Range doesn't working.
Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from shop_cookies_app.models import *
# Create your views here.
def show_catalog(request):
    response = render(request, "catalog.html", context={'products': Product.objects.all()})
    
    if request.method == "POST": 
        # product_count = request.POST.get("product_count")
        # product_count = int(product_count)
        # for i in range(product_count):
            if "product_pk" not in request.COOKIES: 
                product = request.POST.get('product_pk')
                response.set_cookie('product_pk', product)
                return response
            else:
                product = request.COOKIES['product_pk'] + ' ' + request.POST.get('product_pk')  
                response.set_cookie('product_pk', product)
                return response

    return response
```

HTML:

```
    <h1>Каталог</h1>
    {% for product in products %}
        <h2>{{ product.name }}</h2>
        <p>{{ product.desc }}</p>
        <img src="{{ product.image.url }}" alt="">
        <h3 class = "price"><span class = "spanPrice">{{ product.price }}</span> $</h3>
        <div class = "addAndRemove">
            
            <div class = "buttons">
                <button class = "plus">&plus;</button>
                <button class = "minus">&minus;</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form method = "POST" class = "addCookie">
            <!-- action="{% url 'catalog' %}"  -->

            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="product_pk" value="{{ product.pk }}">
            <input class = "count" name = "product_count" value = "1">
            <button class = "addToCart">Додати до кошику</button>
        </form>
    {% endfor %}
    <script src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.js' integrity="sha256-a9jBBRygX1Bh5lt8GZjXDzyOB+bWve9EiO7tROUtj/E=" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
    <script src = '{% static "addCookie.js" %}' defer></script>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // let madeBeforeFunctions = $(".count").val()
    function changeTimesPlus() {
        console.log("plus")
        let a = $(".count").val()
        $(".count").val(++a)
    }
    function changeTimesMinus() {
        console.log("minus")
        if ($(".count").val() > 1) {
            let a = $(".count").val()
            $(".count").val(--a)
        }
    }
    $(".plus").on("click", changeTimesPlus)
    $(".minus").on("click", changeTimesMinus)
    $(".addCookie").on("submit", function (event) {
        // for (let i = 0; i < madeBeforeFunctions; i++) {
        // setTimeout(function (event) { 
        event.preventDefault()
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(".addCookie").action,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) { }
        })
        $(".count").val(1)
        // }, 500)
        // }
    })
})
```

It not depends on product_count, it just doesn't work. Even if you write 99 or something like that, it still won't work.

We have tried to use a lot of ways to solve this problem, and it turns out that the problem is not in our data at all, but in the range itself. When the form fires, it works once.
We even used javascript to solve the problem, but then it got worse, ajax just didn’t work, and this method didn’t work at the same time.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It can not be true, that the range is not working in views, there is a problem with your code not with the range. :D When you return, you are also exiting the for loop containing the range.

Comment: When I removed return (I have just copied the answer), it also not worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is your "return ... " to make your code run and 'for' loop doesn't make any sense to use since it's always set last loop value to key 'product_pk'.

So, try this out in your views.py to add single pk to request cookies:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from shop_cookies_app.models import *
# Create your views here.
def show_catalog(request):
    response = render(request, "catalog.html", context={'products': Product.objects.all()})
    
    if request.method == "POST": 
        product_count = request.POST.get("product_count")
        product_count = int(product_count)
        product = str(request.POST.get('product_pk'))
        if "product_pk" in request.COOKIES: 
            product = '{} {}'.format(request.COOKIES['product_pk'],product)
        
        response.set_cookie('product_pk', product)   

    return response
```

But I think you have other problems. you are trying to add multiple pk as a single key to request cookies. in this case you need to send data in the following format and set them to cookies:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from shop_cookies_app.models import *
# Create your views here.
def show_catalog(request):
    response = render(request, "catalog.html", context={'products': Product.objects.all()})

    if request.method == "POST": 
        product_count = request.POST.get("product_count")
        product_count = int(product_count)
        product = str(request.POST.get('product_pk'))# send a string of PKs separated with space like '1 45 14 2 6'

        for pk in product.split(' '):# split return a list of pk and we run loop on it to get each pk.
        
            # here is your code to run with each pk

            # finally you add PKs to request cookies
            pass
        

        response.set_cookie('product_pk', product)   

    return response
```

Comment: Sadly, it changed nothing but thanks that you're trying to help me.